# Postgres 12 - under which cirumstances should I activate the query and index statistics collector

Tags: postgresql, statistics

**TL;DR - I don't have the collector activated (yet) and it seems to not be the default; how bad is this and should I activate it?**

- I've just created a new index on a table where a query was slow.
- I've done so by running `Explain` on the query and creating indices on various combinations of the tables' / queries' columns.
- I forfeited the indices not being used after running `Explain` again, keeping the one which was used
- Then I decided to check on the statistics gathered for that table. Turns out that `SELECT schemaname, relname, last_analyze FROM pg_stat_all_tables WHERE relname = '<MY TABLE>';` was returning NULL as for the last analyze.
- Checking the `postgresql.conf` I identified that currently I'm not analyzing at all ...

```
...
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# STATISTICS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Query and Index Statistics Collector -

#track_activities = on
#track_counts = on
#track_io_timing = off
#track_functions = none         # none, pl, all
#track_activity_query_size = 1024   # (change requires restart)
#stats_temp_directory = 'pg_stat_tmp'
...
```

### My questions

1. Does the query planner still have enough intell to know when to go for an index vs. doing a full-table scan etc.?
2. When should one consider activating the Query and Index Statistics Collector? (Always, only in certain cirumstances, ...)

Comment: `track_activity_query_size` is only about the length of the queries reported in `pg_stat_activity` it has nothing to do with statistics. `track_io_timings` is also not about the optimizer statistics, it's only there to show you I/O timings in the output of `explain (analyze)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statistics collector is already activated, don't worry.

Note that the statistics that the statistics collector gathers are *not* the table statistics that the optimizer uses, but data about the workload of the database.

The table statistics are collected by autovacuum, which is also enabled by default.

There is a connection between both, in that autovacuum relies on the statistics gathered by the statistics collector to know when it should `ANALYZE` a table.

Answer (score 0):

Are you confused by the settings in the conf file being commented out?  Being commented out doesn't mean it is off, it means it has its compiled-in default value, which is `on` for track_activities and track_counts.  (I would also turn on track_io_timings--it isn't used by the planner, but provides good info for you).

The data in "pg_stat_all_tables" is not very durable.  It is lost every time the server crashes or undergoes an immediate shutdown, or pg_stat_reset() is called.  Now all of those things should be very rare on a production server, but maybe you aren't using a production server for your testing, and anyway they aren't always as rare as they should be.  If you look at pg_stats instead, that will give you a better idea of whether analyze has truly ever been run on the table.